# Why do the limits to the computation of the universe appear to us as fundamental physical constants?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-physics, materialism

According to the Estakhr's [Principle of Physical Constants](http://meetings.aps.org/link/BAPS.2017.NWS.C2.5) Physical Constants are Computational limits or vice versa.

Why do the limits to the computation of the universe appear to us as fundamental physical constants?

Why the computational limits of the Universe from the Big Bang happen to have those values?

Does not that mean we're inside a computer?

Is not the Estakhr's principle of physical constants a **kill shot** to materialistic worldview?

---

**See also:**

- [The simulation hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis)
- [Avatamsaka Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatamsaka_Sutra)
  – a Mahayana Buddhist text describing a cosmos of infinite realms
- [Digital physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics)
- [Holographic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle)
- [Mathematical universe hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis)
- [Simulated reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_reality)
- [George Berkeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Berkeley) -- immaterialism

Comment: It seems very speculative and perhaps too broad for the kind of short answers we try to provide. Regardless, welcome to this SE!

Comment: Maybe it's broad but it seems a good question. I cannot comment but will be interested in the answers.

Comment: In fact.. the main limits (asymptotes..) appear to contradict the idea of computer simulation.